# Why can't the Battle Front fight NPCs?

Tags: angel-beats

After Naoi's taken control of the Student Council she starts using them as shields against the Battle Front because, as Yuri said, they can't attack NPCs.

I would get if it was a moral ground they stood but in the climax we see that a number of the guys following Naoi was holding guns. Sure they might not be able to be killed but it does seem dumb for them to hold back against combatants.

Is there a reason why the Battle Front can't fight armed NPCs?

Answer (score 1):

As I get it, it is just part of their moral code never to fight innocents including NPCs. I don't know why but they say "must not" so it has to be a rule and it is the SSS so it can't be a "Word of God".

There is (as far as I know the anime and the fan wiki) no canon explanation. Maybe they give respect for the possibility of real AIs or that they can't be 100% sure not to missjudge a human for an NPC.

When the Shadows appeard, they had no problem fighting this mutated NPCs but at this point, they could be sure not to deal with a human like consciousness or a real human.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is supposed to be a love comedy so it has to have some stupid moments in there or else it will be just a romance.

Comment: Generally, unless otherwise specified, in-universe questions like this are best answered by an in-universe answer. The producers' considerations when creating the work are also sometimes interesting, but ultimately a different question.